# Internal linking to app page on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi similar to the facebook and iphone app, i have an @ function which should link to the users page. My question is how do i go about doing this, what control should be used, for instance i may have some text like this;

"hey @pablo are you and @paul coming over tomorrow"

In that text @pablo and @paul should be clickable.

I hope i am making sense?. Thanks

Comment: As promised find link to article and source in my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written an article on an **interactive rich text UILabel** and included full source-code... enjoy!

As promised article is [here.....](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/06/interactive-rich-text-uilabel/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a uiwebview to do it and add the text with html to the webview.

Comment: This is not a very nice approach sadly, too much overhead, have to disable scrolling, back shadowing etc etc. Hence why I created a UILabel descendant.